# How can i do the total of price column in listview using visual basic

Tags: vb.net

The code currently i posted have listview related code only.I am having three columns
'Item', 'Quantity', 'Price' and i am having trouble doing total of price column only.
The thing i want to do is like when i click on Total button it should calculate all the price entered and display the total in a textbox.

I am a beginner and learning visual basic so i don't know much about it.

So Please help me.

Here is my code,

```
 Public Class marutiselection

'handles Add Item Button's Click event

Private Sub addButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
   ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addButton.Click

    'clear previous bill totals and calculation result

    If totalcostResultLabel.Text <> "" Then
        totalcostResultLabel.Text = ""
    End If

    Dim lstitm As ListViewIte

    lstitm = ListView1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text)
    lstitm.SubItems.Add(quantityTextBox.Text)
    lstitm.SubItems.Add(priceTextBox.Text)
    quantityTextBox.Clear() ' clear quantity from TextBox
    quantityTextBox.Focus() ' transfer focus to TextBox
    ComboBox1.Text = String.Empty ' clear menu item from TextBox
    ComboBox1.Focus() ' transfer focus to TextBox
    priceTextBox.Clear() ' clear price from TextBox
    priceTextBox.Focus() ' transfer focus to TextBox

End Sub

    Private Sub totalbillButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    Handles totalbillButton.Click

            Const col As Integer = 3
            Dim total As Integer = 0
            Dim lvsi As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem

                For i As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1

                lvsi = ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(col)
                total += Integer.Parse(lvsi.Text)

                Next

                totalcostResultLabel.Text = total

   End Sub

     Private Sub marutiselection_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
     Handles MyBase.Load

               Dat.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
               Timer1.Start()
               Call CenterToScreen()
               Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

                ListView1.Columns.Add("Item", 130, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
                ListView1.Columns.Add("Quantity", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Right)
                ListView1.Columns.Add("Price", 75, HorizontalAlignment.Right)
                ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(""))

    End Sub
  End Class
```

Comment: It appears that you have 3 columns in your ListView. So, the `Price` value is stored in the 3rd Column, which is the SubItem at index `2`: `lvsi = ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(2)`. It's not clear whether you stored the full price there (`(price x item) * NumberOfItems`). If not, get the the value of the SubItem at index `1` and multiply. Don't use the `Integer` type when dealing with curency. Use the `Decimal` type (and `Decimal.Parse()`). But you should really consider the [Decimal.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse) method (for *safety*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `addButton_Click` it really isn't necessary to check the label for an empty string; just set the property.
Before adding a ListViewItem do validation and leave the Sub with a Return statement.
Repeatedly setting the .Focus accomplishes nothing.
You probably want to set focus to the products combo but I will leave that up to you.

In the totalbillButton_Click. The columns in the ListView are zero based meaning that the first column is index 0, second column is index 1 etc. 
Integers are automatically initialized to 0.
You had the right idea looping through the items to get the total but I think you forgot that you need to multiple the quantity x price. It is a bad idea to do arithmetic with strings. So, we convert to the proper datatype to do the multiplication. We know it is a safe conversion because we validated the input.

In the form load don't add a blank row.

I used different names for the controls because they are already set up in my test project.

```vb
'TextBox1 = quantityTextBox
'TextBox2 = priceTextBox
'Label1 = totalcostResultLabel


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Added some data for test
    Dim products() As String = {"Apples", "Oranges", "Pears"}
    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(products)

    TextBox3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Item", 130, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Quantity", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Right)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Price", 75, HorizontalAlignment.Right)

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Private Sub addButton_Click
    'clear previous bill totals and calculation result
    Label1.Text = ""
    'Validate input
    If ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a product")
        ComboBox1.Focus()
        Return
    End If
    Dim i As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, i) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Valid Number")
        TextBox1.Focus()
        Return
    End If
    Dim d As Decimal
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, d) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Valid Number")
        TextBox2.Focus()
        Return
    End If
    'Add the item to the ListView
    Dim lstitm As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text)
    lstitm.SubItems.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    lstitm.SubItems.Add(TextBox2.Text)
    'Clear input data
    TextBox1.Clear() ' clear quantity from TextBox
    ComboBox1.Text = String.Empty ' clear menu item from TextBox
    TextBox2.Clear() ' clear price from TextBox
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Private Sub totalbillButton_Click
    Dim total As Decimal = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        Dim quantity = CInt(ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text)
        Dim price = CDec(ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(2).Text)
        total += quantity * price
    Next
    Label1.Text = total.ToString("N2")
End Sub
```